# How to get the value of Controls added in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

I have a data in my ListView control like:

```
Country  State  City
India    U.P.   Kanpur
India    M.P.   Gwalior
```

Now the problem is I want to add selection in ListView by Radio Button or any other control like:

```
Country  State  City     Choose
India    U.P.   Kanpur   Yes|No
India    M.P.   Gwalior  Yes|No
```

and lastly save the data with their selection.

**Update:-**

I successfully added the controls in listView, now i want to run a loop through all the rows of listview to get the values of each row including the radiobutton.

```
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id";


SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.listview_layout, cursor, new String[] {
                            GridTestActivity.KEY_ROW_ID,
                            GridTestActivity.KEY_ID,
                            GridTestActivity.KEY_DESCRIPTION }, new int[] {
                            R.id.txtLv_id, R.id.txtLvid,
                            R.id.txtLvDescription });
            adapter.setViewResource(R.layout.listview_layout);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            lv.setFocusable(false);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i,
                        long l) {
                    try {

                        int id = v.getSelectedItemPosition();
                        String id1 = (String) lv.getSelectedItem();
                        long id2 = lv.getSelectedItemId();
                        int id3 = i;//Return Row number
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.setStackTrace(null);
                    }
                }
            });

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v) {
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb.getText(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**setOnItemClickListener returns me the row number while for updating the record I need the value of Id.**

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget443"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxWidth="400sp"
    android:minWidth="400sp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="3" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/widget4344"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="400sp"
        android:minWidth="400sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0sp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLv_id"
            android:layout_width="10sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:padding="4sp"
            android:text="@string/txtLv_Id"
            android:textSize="6pt"
            android:visibility="invisible" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLvid"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:padding="4sp"
            android:text="@string/txtLvId"
            android:textSize="6pt" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLvDescription"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:padding="4sp"
            android:text="@string/txtLvDescription"
            android:textSize="6pt" >
        </TextView>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rdGroup"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdYes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/rdYes" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/rdNo" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Here is an example: [Android - Multi Column ListView](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/)

Comment: Don't start your title with [solved]. Either accept an existing answer, or if you've found a solution yourself, make it an actual answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Temporary Solution:))**

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v) {
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    // rb.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    View Rg = (View) rb.getParent();
    View LLayout = (View) Rg.getParent();
    TextView txtLvId = (TextView) LLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtLvid);
    String LvID = txtLvId.getText().toString();

}
```

On the basis of the selected text and corresponding value of the IDColumn save the record in the database instantly.

**Yet I'm looking for the better solution.**

Answer (score 1):

first thing to do it is make it a listview instead of gridview because you have list of row items and then in XML using row layout you can add three TextView's and one Radio button /Checkbox to the view.

Comment: yep I done it.. now the problem is I need to update the database according to the selection made by the user.

Comment: well, on every radio button/checkbox add an listener and then when user clicks on it you can do anything with that data in listener

Comment: I have only one radiogroup in my XML and it's created no. of times the row exists.I think, I need to run a for loop but can't figure out how to get the values of each row.

Comment: in your listadapter add listener to every inflated view's radiogroup